# Searching in a list

Tags: ocaml

I have a problem when I try to modify a list. I have a `(string*float) list` and I have to change it on the following way:

```
    1. If I find an existing string in the list, i have to change his value
    2. Else I have to add the pair string(name) * float (value) to the list (don't care the position)
```

I show you the code with mistakes:

```
exception Not_found;;

let rec searchMake l var = match l with
    []-> raise Not_found
    | (h,x)::t-> if h=var then (h,x)
             else (h,x)::(searchMake t var);;   

let make varlist (var,value) =
    try
        let p=searchMake varlist var in
        snd p <- value
    with Not_found -> varlist <- (var, value)::varlist;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists, tuples and variables are immutable in OCaml, so you cannot assign to them with `<-`. Instead, write a function that returns a new list that has the properties you want.

Comment: Problem solved, instead of returning a tuple, I just return the float value, so I can change it easily. Sorry for losing your time :(